# Accurate pandoc gfm conversion

Tags: html, pandoc, github-flavored-markdown

In the [online documentation](https://pandoc.org/getting-started.html), there is a step where `pandoc` is used to convert a file from markdown to html.

If I instead denote the input file to be in GitHub Flavoured Markdown format, like:

```
pandoc test.md -f gfm -t html -s -o test.html
```

the resultant html file does not have the code block shading and lines under headings, that would be there if I create an `.md` file on GitHub.

Am I missing something in my command?

Comment: that has nothing to do with the markdown flavour, but it's simply about adding CSS.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Would the CSS be added to the pandoc command?

Comment: use something like `pandoc --css=foo.css --self-contained -s input.md -o output.html`